# Proving Axler Theorem 3.36

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove Axler 3.36, which is as follows (paraphrased):

> Suppose $S$ and $T$ are linear maps from $V$ to $W$. Then the matrix of $(S + T)$ is equal to the matrix of $S$ plus the matrix of $T$. (Assume that the same bases have been chosen for all three maps.)

He defines the sum of two matrices in terms of the mechanical operation,
$$
(A + C)_{j,k} = A_{j,k} + C_{j,k}.
$$
It seems that the matrix sum isn't given, by definition, the interpretation of a linear transformation relative to a basis, but this formula gives us that interpretation as the transformation $(S + T)$ relative to the bases. Is that the correct way to interpret this? (So prior to this theorem, matrix addition was a purely mechanical process.)

Here is my attempt at proving it.

> Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be a basis for $V$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ a basis for $W$. We will prove that the $k$th column of the matrices $\mathcal{M}(S + T)$ is equal to the $k$th column of the matrix $\mathcal{M}(S) + \mathcal{M}(T)$. Relative to the chosen basis, we have
> $$
> Sv_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m S_{i,k} u_i \qquad Tv_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m T_{i,k} u_i.
> $$
> That is, the $k$th column of $S$ is given by $S_{1,k}, S_{2,k}, \ldots, S_{m,k}$ and the $k$th column of $T$ is given by $T_{1,k}, T_{2,k}, \ldots, T_{m,k}$. By the definition of matrix addition, the $k$th column of $\mathcal{M}(S) + \mathcal{M}(T)$ consists of $S_{1,k} + T_{1,k}, S_{2,k} + T_{2,k}, \ldots, S_{m,k} + T_{m,k}$.
>
> Now, we consider $\mathcal{M}(S + T)$. We have
> \begin{align*}
> (S+T)v_k &= Sv_k + Tv_k \\
> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^m S_{i,k} u_i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m T_{i,k} u_i \\
> &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^m (S_{i,k} + T_{i,k}) u_i,
> \end{align*}
> so the $k$th column of $\mathcal{M}(S + T)$ consists of $S_{1,k} + T_{1,k}, \ldots, S_{m,k} + T_{m,k}$. As this holds for all $1 \leq k \leq n$, we conclude that $\mathcal{M}(S + T) = \mathcal{M}(S) + \mathcal{M}(T)$.

How does this attempt look?

Comment: It is ok.______

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. Am I correct that matrix addition a priori is a purely mechanical process, given an interpretation only by this theorem?

Comment: Yes you are. __

Comment: A more crisp way to write all this, would be to use the  basis and the dual basis and to use the fact that $S_{ij}= f_j^*(S(e_i))$. Then the requested result is almost one line.

Comment: You use $wi$ as the basis for W, but then you express $S_{v_k}$ and $T_{v_k}$ in terms of $ui$. Shouldn't $ui$ be $wi$?